# Select rows with same id and rewrite id grouped by id

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
+------+------+
| AID  | NAME |
+------+------+
|  1   | A    |
|  2   | A    |
|  3   | A    |
|  4   | B    |
|  5   | B    |
+------+------+
```

and with a "select" the output should be something like:

```
+------+------+------+
| AID  | NAME | NEWID|
+------+------+------+
|  1   | A    |  1   |
|  2   | A    |  2   |
|  3   | A    |  3   |
|  4   | B    |  1   |
|  5   | B    |  2   |
+------+------+------+
```

I have to use only SQL, a stored procedure, or functions.

I do not know how to write the query without using a stored procedure.

Who can help me?

Nicola

Comment: Tag the DBMS (i.e. `MySQL`, `SQL Server`, etc...) that you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `row_number()` :

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by name order by id) as newid
from table t;
```

**EDIT :** You can also use correlated subquery :

```
select t.*,
       (select count(*)
        from table t1
        where t1.name = t.name and t1.id <= t.id
       ) as newid
from table t;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but ...
MySQL introduced the ROW_NUMBER () function from version 8.0. I use version 5.6, but thanks to you I found how to emulate it (http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-row_number)
The query must be run in 2 different DBMS, FIREBIRD and MySQL, so I have to write in standard SQL. If it not possible, I have to do 2 different queries based on the server, Mysql is ok

Comment: @NicolaChinea. . . Then `correlated` subquery will help.